# Python module being reimported when imported at different places

Tags: python

I am relatively new to python and I have a simple python module with some constants which are being modified by some code in other files.  I want these to be the same through out. i.e

a.py

```
start = True
```

b.py

```
import a
while(a.start):
 //do something
```

c.py

```
import a
a.start =False
```

My understanding of a python module is, it acts like a singleton and any module is imported only once. So, when I try running `b.py` and then run `c.py`, what I am expecting would be this:

- `b.py` loops
- `c.py` sets start to false
- `b.py` stops looping as they are importing from the same module

But, when I run this I think what is happening is module is being re-imported as a duplicate and by `b.py` never stops running. Is there something I am doing something very basic wrong?

Comment: Well the first very basic thing you're doing wrong is posting impossible code as an example. Module names can't start with a number. Can you post the actual code that isn't working, or a minimal test case that shows the problem? Can just be `a.py`, `b.py`, `c.py`, but it's gotta be runnable to be debuggable.

Comment: 2nd issue: it sounds like you're running python twice. Modules are singletons *within* a single python process - oh, nvm, see below.

Comment: Are you using threads? Otherwise first `while` will loop forever and it will never reach the other import.

Answer (score 5):

Python modules are singletons **within one run of the interpreter**.

Running `c.py` in a *separate* process will not alter the value of `start` in another Python interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do here?

Comment: What *are* you trying to do? Threading, multiprocessing, understanding how a sequence of imports works?

Comment: I have been reading up a lot on python threads since yesterday and still haven't a concrete idea as to how this can be achieved. Could you give me an example of how this can be done?

Comment: That is too broad a subject for a set of comments, I fear.

Comment: @vectro404 Threads aren't the only answer, especially not in Python, what with the GIL. Take a look at my answer, which shows simple interprocess communication using a file. Sure, the solution is unsophisticated and flawed in corner cases (it busyloops if the `while` body does very little works), but it does work and it does answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

As Martijn explained, Python modules are singletons within the same process. To achieve what you are trying to do, you need to implement some form of interprocess communication. To take a trivial example, you could write to a file:

```
# a.py
import os

REQUEST_FILE = 'stop-request'

def should_stop():
    return os.path.exists(REQUEST_FILE)

def clear():
    if os.path.exists(REQUEST_FILE):
        os.unlink(REQUEST_FILE)

def request_stop():
    with open(REQUEST_FILE, 'w'):
        pass

# b.py
import a
a.clear()     # avoid leftover stop-request stopping us before we've started
while not a.should_stop():
    # ... do something ...

# c.py
import a
a.request_stop()
```